# Creating a numpy array for multiple datasets

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have many datasets, all with the shape of `(586, 1383)`, which represent the longitude and latitude respectively. The datasets are for soil moisture data; for example, `print(dataset1[2, 435])` will give me a value of `0.354`.

Currently, I have 31 of these datasets. I want to create a numpy array with a shape of `(31, 586, 1383)` to hold all these datasets. I can currently open all the datasets I want to add to an array like so:

```
directory = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\AMSRE"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for f in filenames:
        if f.startswith("AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001"):
        log = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r')
        file_name = (("C:\\Users\\matth\\Downloads\\AMSRE\\") + f)
        hdf = SD(file_name, SDC.READ)
        g = gdal.Open(('HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:') + file_name + (':Ascending_Land_Grid:A_Soil_Moisture'))
        sm = g.ReadAsArray()

        lons = np.fromstring ( urllib2.urlopen("ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/tools/easegrid/lowres_latlon/MLLONLSB").read(), \
        dtype=np.int32 )/100000.
        lats = np.fromstring ( urllib2.urlopen("ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/tools/easegrid/lowres_latlon/MLLATLSB").read(), \
        dtype=np.int32 )/100000.

        lons = lons.reshape(sm.shape)
        lats = lats.reshape(sm.shape)
        smm = np.ma.array ( sm, mask=np.logical_or ( sm==-9999, sm==9999))
```

In the end, `print(smm.shape)` gives me `(586, 1383)`. The code above was to just get the data in terms of latitude and longitude. I was thinking of maybe using a `for` loop to consecutively add the files into an empty array... not sure how that will work though. Does anyone know how I can work with this code, or change it, so I can add the datasets into an array with a shape of `(31, 586, 1383)`?

Comment: Why not just `pd.DataFrame(smm)`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the size of the dataframe was still `(586, 1383)`

Comment: Ah.. didn't see that bit. Not sure how well pandas supports 3D data frames.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is it possible to read this into a `numpy` array?

Comment: Is it not already a numpy array?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I mean combine them into a numpy array with a shape of `(31, 586, 1383)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) DataFrame is a 2D structure.

> DataFrame is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table, or a dict of Series objects.

But you can have a list of dataframes or all your data in same dataframe with an additional column which indicates the origin.